# How to reproject all featureclasses in a database to another database?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-desktop

I am very new to arcpy and have ArcGIS 10.0

I would like to make a script where I would only have to change two variables in a script (database_input and database_output) so that I can reproject all vector featureclasses within the database and save them into another database(which exists already).

Would anyone be able to put me on the right track?

My code so far. It is basically an exported modelbuilder model using the batch reproject tool.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
shp1 = "Path_to_Geodatabase_old\\old.gdb\\shp1"
shp2 = "Path_to_Geodatabase_new\\new.gdb\\shp2"
test_etrs_gdb__2_ = "G:\\Tifosy_Serverinstall\\test_etrs.gdb"

# Process: Batch-Projizierung
arcpy.BatchProject_management("Path_to_Geodatabase_old\\old.gdb\\shp1;Path_to_Geodatabase_new\\new.gdb\\shp2", test_etrs_gdb__2_, "PROJCS['ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_N32',GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',32500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',9.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "", "DHDN_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached script adds feature datasets (FDs) and featureclasses (FCs) from an old file geodatabase (FGDB) to an *existing* FGDB.  I've added some logic to check for potentially problematic null data and FCs with no spatial information.  Essentially this script performs the following actions:

1. Create new feature datasets (if they exist) in target FGDB with the new projection.
2. Copies all of the old FCs to the new FGDB FDs.
3. Checks for stand alone FCs in the old FGDB.
4. If stand alone FCs exist, copy them to the new FGD.

---

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Set this to the input FGDB
env.workspace = r'C:\temp\old_gdb.gdb'
Dir = env.workspace

env.overwriteOutput = 1

# Variables
gdb_out = r'C:\temp\new_gdb.gdb'
sr = r'C:\my_custom_projections\NRCS_USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic.prj' 

##################################
# Parameters for script tool

# Input FGDB
#env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Target FGDB
#gdb_out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

##################################

# List the old FDs
dslist = arcpy.ListDatasets("", "Feature")

# Add old FDs to target FGDB (FC will be projected in new FDs)
if dslist == "Null":
    pass

else:
    for ds in dslist:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management (gdb_out, ds, sr)

        # List FCs in FDs and copy them to new FDs
        fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","",ds)
        for fc in fclist:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(gdb_out, ds, fc))

# Finally, add/project any standalone FCs to the new FGDB
for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        ds = arcpy.Describe(infc)
        if ds.featureType == "Simple":

            # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
            dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

            if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
                print ('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + infc)
            else:      
                # run project tool
                arcpy.Project_management(infc, os.path.join(gdb_out, infc), sr)
        else:
            print 'No stand alone feature classes to copy'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You need to get a input/output workspaces from user, get list of the feature classes first, then perform the Project tool for each item in the list:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 11N') #define the CS here
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs: 
    outfc = os.path.join(output_folder, fc)

    # Run the Project tool to project fcs from the workspace to an output workspace
    #
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, outCS)
```

If you scroll down in the help page, there is actually a sample script for that.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000

Comment: NameError: name 'infc' is not defined

Comment: The one above should work fine

Comment: No, I´m afraid not.

Comment: Please update the code in your script tool. The "infc" is not something that is used in the code snippet above.

Comment: How do you address copying/projecting feature classes within feature datasets?  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Aaron, I have not shown how to do this in the script because was no question regarding this. Robert was looking for a way to get started writing a script with a functionality outlined and I believe the code and comments I've provided are sufficient to "put him on the right track" as asked :)